# Chain Homotopy in abelian category

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

When dealing with complexes of modules or groups, the following lemma is pretty easy:

> If $f,g :E\rightarrow E'$ are homotopic, i.e. $f-g=d'h+hd$ for some h, then $f,g$ induce the same homomorphism on the homology $H(E)$, i.e. $H(f_n)=G(g_n):H^n(E)\rightarrow H^n(E')$.
>
> *proof*: Given $x \in$  kernel of $d^n$, the homotopy condition shows that $(f_n-g_n)(x)$ is contained in the boundaries, that is, in the image of $d'^{(n-1)}.$

But how to prove it if complexes are formed from **abelian category**?

I know the corresponding definition of homology (They are of the form $\text{Coker}\,(\text{Im}\,(d^{(i)}) \to \text{Ker}\,(d^{(i+1)}))$ in my mind), but then I don't know how to deal with it, the ordinary proof just doesn't translate to abelian category to me, for example I can't pick elements in the object, help please.

Comment: What is the "ordinary" proof? The standard proofs I know involve a lot of diagram chasing and work pretty well in an Abelian Category with the suitable lemmas. Alternativly, you can try to embed your abelian category into the category of modules by Gabriel's Theorem

Comment: @Kamina I have edited it to add the proof.

Comment: You can use "generalized elements" as explained in McLane's book.

Comment: Have you tried proving some of the simpler facts without using elements?